# Long running ajax call in Laravel pausing the server

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-8

I am trying to build a video editing application in Laravel 8. When you click on a button it calls a route through ajax that runs a shell_exec command that can take 10 minutes or more to run.

It is running a ffmpeg command. I want the page to know when the script has finished, so that it can reload the video in the browser, but it is also important that the script keeps running if the user closes their browser.

That all works, but the problem is that all pages on the site are frozen and can't be loaded until ffmpeg has finished - that is, all pages in localhost:8000. Pages on localhost/ are all good.

I read that the solution is to put session_write_close() before shell_exec and that in Laravel you should put session()->save() or $request->session()->save(); ? But nothing I have tried makes any difference.

Thanks in advance, if anyone can help out with this.

Comment: I dont know if this will help you or not but have you tried running the exec command with "nohup" Basically nohup sends the exec command in the background where the page is still usable and can do whatever you want.

Use the script that exec is calling to update the database when video is done processing and Then i would use a ajax call (maybe every 5 seconds) to check perhaps a database update when the video is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was because it was running the Laravel app with 'php artisan serve', which uses php's built in server and is only designed for development.

When I readjusted the code to have it running in apache, without having to run php artisan serve, it was able to have multiple instances of ffmpeg running at the same time.

Hope this helps someone.